# Best way to compile user data every month even if app is closed

Tags: swift, xcode

In my app, I'm making a graph the tracks a users balance for every month. The only problem I have is that I can't find a way to run a function at the end of every month to find the balance and add it to an array for the graph. What's a way I could do this. I'm also using Firebase real-time database if there is a way I could use that.  Thanks for any help in advance.

**EDIT:**
Can firebase take data from the real-time database sort it, put it in an array, and send it back to the database for the app to use instead?

Comment: If the app hasn’t been used then nothing has happened to the balance right? So what difference would it make to collect the data the first time the app is opened each month whenever that is?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I updated my question to ask about maybe a different way. I can't figure out a way to have an array update with the months that didn't change even when it is in use. Do you know a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can then use a quiet push (Data Message) with the new settings you want to update in the app. Try Firebase Cloud Message along with Firebase Remote Config.

- [Firebase Remote Config [Docs]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/)
- [Firebase Cloud Message [Concept Options]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)